# int value still remain the same when UIViewController dismissed iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, int

I give an example:

I am using two view controllers, lets name it Home and Sales. Firstly, i navigate from Home To Sales using push. In Sales view controller i have globally declared an int value and assign it to zero. Like this:

```
int example_int = 0;
```

After that, there is some process that going in Sales View Controller, and **example_int** value changed, for example it has value of **2**. Next, it navigate back to Home using pop. For testing purpose, i navigate back to Sales and i **NSLog example_int**, it gave the same value of 2.

This gave me problem initially. But i have solved it by using func: viewWillDismiss and assign the example_int to 0(default value). So for now, i m just curios what is going on here.Thank you.

Comment: You can set example_int value as 0 at viewDidDisappear or viewDidUnLoad..To make as initial value to 0 everytime u came to Sales View...If u pop to some view then the assigned values still exists..for object.If u push then the values will re-assigned to default values..like 0...!

Comment: The global var's life will persist across entire app's life. if you want a var associated with sales view controller instance, you should use a instance var to save data.

Answer (score 1):

The global variable will persist through out the app life cycle, if the use of example_int variable is limited to sales view than in that case you should create example_int as the member variable of sales view controller. If at all there is a requirement to keep the example_int variable as global than in that case you need to reset the value of example_int to 0 as per your requirement (in your case inside viewDidDisappear or viewDidUnLoad methods of sales view controller).